# python suds -- WSDL contains enumeration values with accents

Tags: python, utf-8, suds

I never had any problem using suds before, until I hit this WSDL. (this is just the part that causes problems)

```
<s:simpleType name="ProductFormat">
   <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="Papier"/>
      <s:enumeration value="Numérique"/>
      <s:enumeration value="PapierEtNumérique"/>
   </s:restriction>
</s:simpleType>
```

As you can see, there is accents in values and suds is buzzing when I try to create:

```
product_format = self.client.factory.create('ProductFormat')
```

This is the end of the traceback:

```
File "/home/andre/Documents/archambault/apps/onix/management/commands/import_sogides_onix.py", line 58, in get_catalog
    product_format = self.client.factory.create('ProductFormat')
  File "/home/andre/Documents/archambault/envs/lib/python2.6/site-packages/suds/client.py", line 240, in create
    setattr(result, e.name, e.name)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Looks like Suds doesn't like the "é" of Numérique (position 3). to your knowledge, is there a way to avoid editing client.py ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suds interface transforms these enumerations into object attributes, and Python 2.* does not allow unicode glyphs for identifier names. In Python 3.2 this works:

```
>>> class A(object):
        pass

>>> a = A()
>>> setattr(a, 'tést', 1)
>>> a.tést
1
```

In Python 2.6 this raises UnicodeEncodeError:

```
>>> setattr(a, u'tést', 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Fixing this for Python 2.* seems like a lot of work:

- check if `e.name != unidecode(e.name)`, if so convert identifiers to ascii using 
  unidecode and keep track of the original name.
- convert back to the unicode version when generating soap messages

I never tried suds with Python 3.*, but it supports unicode letters in identifier names.

My native idiom is Portuguese, which has lots of accented characters like the French in this WSDL. Even if Python 3.* allows for that, I think there is no compelling reason for using anything but English identifiers - it's a dumb idea and the interface author is asking for trouble. The whole idea behind SOAP is interoperability, why use a feature that is not well supported by all programming languages?

Comment: Thanks Paulo, you confirm my fears. I was playing around with e.name and decode(), but when it worked, it couldn't find "Numérique" anymore. I didn't feel like converting it back so I wrote here..

Comment: @user112342: Sorry to hear that. Are you in a hurry? May be I could fix it for you, can I access this webservice through an Internet URL?

Comment: Nice of you to offer, but it's password protected... Thanks though!